# Converting nested dictionary to dataframe with node levels

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

i've the following dict

```
{8582: {
        "Amounts": 35892,
        8586: {
            "Amounts": 8955,
            8590: {"Amounts": 399},
            8674: {"Amounts": 111},
            8589: {"Amounts": 8445},},
        8585: {"Amounts": 13232, 8588: {"Amounts": 3884}, 8587: {"Amounts": 9348}},
        8593: {"Amounts": 8559, 8583: {"Amounts": 8559}},
        8584: {"Amounts": 5146, 8597: {"Amounts": 5146}},}}
```

it's structure looks like this :
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is the following :
The values in black first 3 cols are ids and values in red are amounts.

I'm open for converting dict to json or playing around with it levels aren't set they can be up until 17 levels but in this example there's only three

here's my attempts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([[k1, k2, v]
              for k1,d in data.items()
              for k2,v in d.items()])
```

or

```
def flatten_dict(d, parent_keys = None):
    if parent_keys is None:
        parent_keys = []

    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        keys = parent_keys + [k]
        if isinstance(v, int):
            items.append({"Keys": keys, "Amounts": v})
        else:
            items.extend(flatten_dict(v, keys))
    return items


flat_data = flatten_dict(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
```

[image]

Comment: @СергейКох my attempts are all wrong ....

Comment: @Gogo78, No wonder that your attempts are wrong, otherwise you wouldn't posted your question, right? But that's about the rue of etiquette of this forum which is not a free coding service. You have to show your attempt irrespective whether it's incorrect or relatively correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) as hinted by @СергейКох and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
s = pd.json_normalize(dic).iloc[0]

df = (s.index
      .str.removesuffix('.Amounts')
      .str.split('.', expand=True)
      .to_frame().notna()
      .where(lambda d: d & ~d.shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value=False)
            )
      .mul(s.values, axis=0)
      )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    0      1     2
8582 NaN  NaN   35892    NaN   NaN
     8586 NaN     NaN   8955   NaN
          8590    NaN    NaN   399
          8674    NaN    NaN   111
          8589    NaN    NaN  8445
     8585 NaN     NaN  13232   NaN
          8588    NaN    NaN  3884
          8587    NaN    NaN  9348
     8593 NaN     NaN   8559   NaN
          8583    NaN    NaN  8559
     8584 NaN     NaN   5146   NaN
          8597    NaN    NaN  5146
```

*NB the leading levels of the MultiIndew are not really blank but just hidden by the display. If you really need blank values, then use the same logic as just before the `mul` and convert back to MultiIndex.*

```
idx = (s.index
      .str.removesuffix('.Amounts')
      .str.split('.', expand=True)
      .to_frame()
      .where(lambda d: (x:=d.notna()) & ~x.shift(-1, axis=1, fill_value=False)
            )
      )

df = (idx.notna().mul(s.values, axis=0)
      .where(idx.notna())
      .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx))      )
```

Output:

```
                      0        1       2
0    1    2                             
8582 NaN  NaN   35892.0      NaN     NaN
NaN  8586 NaN       NaN   8955.0     NaN
     NaN  8590      NaN      NaN   399.0
          8674      NaN      NaN   111.0
          8589      NaN      NaN  8445.0
     8585 NaN       NaN  13232.0     NaN
     NaN  8588      NaN      NaN  3884.0
          8587      NaN      NaN  9348.0
     8593 NaN       NaN   8559.0     NaN
     NaN  8583      NaN      NaN  8559.0
     8584 NaN       NaN   5146.0     NaN
     NaN  8597      NaN      NaN  5146.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a hack which is definitely not the best solution. It is a simplified algorithm to get you started and get a better solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

dict_data = {
    8582: {
        "Amounts": 35892,
        8586: {
            "Amounts": 8955,
            8590: {"Amounts": 399},
            8674: {"Amounts": 111},
            8589: {"Amounts": 8445},
        },
        8585: {"Amounts": 13232, 8588: {"Amounts": 3884}, 8587: {"Amounts": 9348}},
        8593: {"Amounts": 8559, 8583: {"Amounts": 8559}},
        8584: {"Amounts": 5146, 8597: {"Amounts": 5146}},
    }
}


def iterate_dict(dict_data, depth=1, item_idx=0, labels=None, amounts=None):
    for key, value in dict_data.items():
        if key == "Amounts":
            amounts.iloc[item_idx - 1, depth] = value

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            s = pd.Series([None, None, None, None], index=["depth0", "depth1", "depth2", "depth3"])
            item_idx += 1
            labels.loc[item_idx] = s
            amounts.loc[item_idx] = s
            labels.iloc[item_idx - 1, depth] = key

            item_idx = iterate_dict(value, depth + 1, item_idx, labels, amounts)

    return item_idx


labels = pd.DataFrame(columns=["depth0", "depth1", "depth2", "depth3"])
amounts = pd.DataFrame(columns=["depth0", "depth1", "depth2", "depth3"])

iterate_dict(dict_data, 0, 0, labels, amounts)

labels = labels.drop("depth3", axis=1)
amounts = amounts.drop("depth0", axis=1)

final = pd.concat([labels, amounts], axis=1)

print(final)


#    depth0 depth1 depth2 depth1 depth2 depth3
# 1    8582   None   None  35892   None   None
# 2    None   8586   None   None   8955   None
# 3    None   None   8590   None   None    399
# 4    None   None   8674   None   None    111
# 5    None   None   8589   None   None   8445
# 6    None   8585   None   None  13232   None
# 7    None   None   8588   None   None   3884
# 8    None   None   8587   None   None   9348
# 9    None   8593   None   None   8559   None
# 10   None   None   8583   None   None   8559
# 11   None   8584   None   None   5146   None
# 12   None   None   8597   None   None   5146
```

It uses two dataframes that are concatenated at the end. I also had some troubles with indices so I had to remove some columns before merging. There is definitely a better solution to that, but it seems to do the job!

Comment: Wow amazing, it's working thanks but the problem is we had to set cols but my dataset can have alot of levels depends on every dict but the structure of my dict will always be the same, here we have 3 levels but some case we have more ... I don't know if theres a way to move out of hardcoding cols and indexes

Comment: Yes I suspected that, as my solution is not generic at all! What I would do as a hack is to make a more than necessary large amount of columns, and get the max_depth returned by the recursive function alongside the item_idx. That way you know how many columns to crop at the end. And you iterate over the nested dict only once. It assumes that the dict iteration is the time consuming operation, and that memory allocation is not an issue.

Comment: If it does not take too long to iterate over the data twice, it is much easier. First iteration: you get the number of indices and the max_depth. Then you pre-allocate empty dataframes. And second iteration: you fill the dataframes!

Answer (score 0):

An interesting picture is obtained if you read your dictionary using `pd.json_normalize`, and transpose df:

```
import pandas as pd


amounts = {8582: {
        "Amounts": 35892,
        8586: {
            "Amounts": 8955,
            8590: {"Amounts": 399},
            8674: {"Amounts": 111},
            8589: {"Amounts": 8445},},
        8585: {"Amounts": 13232, 8588: {"Amounts": 3884}, 8587: {"Amounts": 9348}},
        8593: {"Amounts": 8559, 8583: {"Amounts": 8559}},
        8584: {"Amounts": 5146, 8597: {"Amounts": 5146}},}}


df = pd.json_normalize(amounts).T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            0
8582.Amounts            35892
8582.8586.Amounts        8955
8582.8586.8590.Amounts    399
8582.8586.8674.Amounts    111
8582.8586.8589.Amounts   8445
8582.8585.Amounts       13232
8582.8585.8588.Amounts   3884
8582.8585.8587.Amounts   9348
8582.8593.Amounts        8559
8582.8593.8583.Amounts   8559
8582.8584.Amounts        5146
8582.8584.8597.Amounts   5146
```

All nesting levels are immediately visible.

Let's remove `.Amounts`, split the rows into lists, and create a multi-index using an additional dataframe.

```
index_multi= df.index.str.removesuffix(".Amounts").str.split('.')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index_multi.values.tolist()).add_prefix('index_').fillna('')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                             0
index_0 index_1 index_2       
8582                     35892
        8586              8955
                8590       399
                8674       111
                8589      8445
        8585             13232
                8588      3884
                8587      9348
        8593              8559
                8583      8559
        8584              5146
                8597      5146
```

Closer to what you need.
It remains to split column `0` into several, depending on the nesting level of the multi-index. But I think I'll leave it to you :). Good luck!

Comment: but this does not place "Amounts" values into different columns as OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive function approach (to unnest the levels to locators) combined with vectorized operations (to construct the final DataFrame):

```
def unnest_levels_to_locators(d: dict, key_amt_locators=None, depth=0):
    if key_amt_locators is None:
        key_amt_locators = []
        # the implied structure: [<row>, <column>, <key>, <amounts>]

    if d.get('Amounts'):
        # connect 'Amounts' value with its parent key
        key_amt_locators[-1][-1] = d['Amounts']

    for k, v in ((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != 'Amounts'):
        if not key_amt_locators:
            # initiate the 1st entry-locator
            key_amt_locators.append([0, 0, k, None])
        else:
            key_amt_locators.append([key_amt_locators[-1][0] + 1, depth, k, None])
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            unnest_levels_to_locators(v, key_amt_locators, depth + 1)

    return key_amt_locators

def make_key_amounts_df(d: dict):
    key_amt_locators = np.array(unnest_levels_to_locators(d))
    shape = (key_amt_locators.shape[0], key_amt_locators[:, 1].max() + 1)
    a_keys = np.full(shape, np.nan)
    a_amounts = np.full(shape, np.nan)
    # fill keys values
    a_keys[key_amt_locators[:, 0], key_amt_locators[:, 1]] = key_amt_locators[:, 2]
    # fill amounts values
    a_amounts[key_amt_locators[:, 0], key_amt_locators[:, 1]] = key_amt_locators[:, -1]

    return pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([a_keys, a_amounts]))


print(make_key_amounts_df(data))
```

---

```
         0       1       2        3        4       5
0   8582.0     NaN     NaN  35892.0      NaN     NaN
1      NaN  8586.0     NaN      NaN   8955.0     NaN
2      NaN     NaN  8590.0      NaN      NaN   399.0
3      NaN     NaN  8674.0      NaN      NaN   111.0
4      NaN     NaN  8589.0      NaN      NaN  8445.0
5      NaN  8585.0     NaN      NaN  13232.0     NaN
6      NaN     NaN  8588.0      NaN      NaN  3884.0
7      NaN     NaN  8587.0      NaN      NaN  9348.0
8      NaN  8593.0     NaN      NaN   8559.0     NaN
9      NaN     NaN  8583.0      NaN      NaN  8559.0
10     NaN  8584.0     NaN      NaN   5146.0     NaN
11     NaN     NaN  8597.0      NaN      NaN  5146.0
```